# MySQL Workbench Visual Explain not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to see the visual explain plan of my query in mysql workbench. But when I click on execution plan it shows tabular plan in default when I change the plan to Visual Plan; nothing happens and it keeps on displaying tabular plan.

I have mySQL 10 and Workbench 8.0.18. 
I have surfed internet alot but found only one solution to upgrade mysql and workbench. I did but still same issue..

Can anyone suggest what is the reason behind that?

Comment: Check the log of MySQL Workbench (Help -> Show Log File). Do you see an error (start scanning from the end of the log)?

Comment: it says => No JSON data for explain

Comment: Sounds like no JSON data was returned from the explain call. Is it a valid statement? Can you run it in the mysql terminal to see the output in raw form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the support, I have resolved the problem now. I was having MySQL Server 5.5 which does not support json. Thats why, Visual Explain plan was not available. Now Upgrading to 8.0 version worked things out for me..

You have to download a mysql installer and execute, and click on 'Add' and select mysql version from there. Afterwards, it will ask for configurations and you will be able to access that version in workbench after installation.

Thanks alot..